# Odoo 11 Qweb Report empty page

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11, qweb

I am trying to create a qweb report for Odoo 11 but without any success. 0 byte pdf I am getting, I edit the report to qweb-html and then only white page. Please help me to solve the issue. Below is my code. I am a beginner and trying to create this report after reading different posts and different modules.
Below is my code in 4 seprate files.

**1st file**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class TrueReportFields(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'true.report'


    @api.multi
    def print_true_report(self):
        sales = self.env['sale.order'].sudo().search(
            [('state', 'in', ('sale', 'done'))])
        total_sale = total_cost = 0
        for sale in sales:
            total_sale += sale.amount_total
            for lines in sale.order_line:
                total_cost += lines.product_id.standard_price * lines.product_uom_qty

        purchases = self.env['purchase.order'].sudo().search(
            [('state', 'not in', ('draft', 'canceled'))])
        total_purchase = 0
        for purchase in purchases:
            total_purchase += purchase.amount_total
        pos_sales = self.env['pos.order'].sudo().search(
            [('state', 'not in', ['cancel', 'draft'])])
        total_pos_sale = total_pos_cost = 0
        for pos in pos_sales:
            total_pos_sale += pos.amount_total
            for posl in pos.lines:
                total_pos_cost += posl.product_id.standard_price * posl.qty

        datas = {
            'ids': self,
            'model': 'true.report',
            'total_sale': total_sale,
            'total_cost': total_cost,
            'total_purchase': total_purchase,
            'total_pos_sale': total_pos_sale,
            'total_pos_cost': total_pos_cost
        }
        return self.env.ref('true_report.action_true_report').report_action(self, data=datas)
```

**2nd file**

```
from odoo import api, models

class TrueReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.true_report.report_details'

    @api.model
    def get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
        return {
            'doc_ids': data.get('ids'),
            'doc_model': data.get('model'),
            'total_sale': data['total_sale'],
            'total_cost': data['total_cost'],
            'total_purchase': data['total_purchase'],
            'total_pos_sale': data['total_pos_sale'],
            'total_pos_cost': data['total_pos_cost']
        }
```

**xml views**

```
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_true_report" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.detail.form</field>
            <field name="model">true.report</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="True Details">
                    <!--<group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="start_date"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="end_date"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>-->
                    <footer>
                        <button string='Print' name="print_true_report" type="object" default_focus="1"
                                class="oe_highlight"/>
                        <button string="Cancel" class="btn-default" special="cancel"/>
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="open_true_report_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Top Sold Products</field>
            <field name="res_model">true.report</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_true_report"/>
        </record>
        <menuitem
                id="menu_true_report"
                name="True Report"
                parent="sale.menu_sale_report"
                sequence="4"
                action="true_report.open_true_report_action"/>

        <report
                id="action_true_report"
                string="True PDF Report"
                model="true.report"
                report_type="qweb-pdf"
                file="true_report.report_details"
                name="true_report.report_details"
        />
    </data>
</odoo>
```

**xml templates**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="report_details_documents">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <t t-set="o" t-value="doc.with_context({'lang':doc.partner_id.lang})" />
            <!--<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">-->
            <!--<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">-->
                <t t-call="web.external_layout">
                    <div class="page">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="oe_structure"/>
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="font-size: 25px;">True Report Details</span>
                        </div>

                        <!--<div class="row mt32 mb32">
                            <div class="col-xs-4">
                                <p>
                                    <t>
                                        <strong>From Date :</strong>
                                        <span t-esc="o.start_date"/>
                                        <br/>
                                    </t>
                                    <t>
                                        <strong>To Date :</strong>
                                        <span t-esc="o.end_date"/>
                                    </t>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>-->

                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Total Sales</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Total Cost</th>
                                    <th>Total Purchase</th>
                                    <th>Pos Sale</th>
                                    <th>Pos Cost</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-esc="o.total_sale"/>
                                    </td>
<!--                                    <td class="text-right" style="white-space: text-nowrap;">
                                        <span t-esc="o.total_cost"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-esc="o.total_purchase"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-esc="o.total_pos_sale"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-esc="o.total_pos_cost"/>
                                    </td>-->
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            <!--</t>-->
        </t>
    </template>
    <template id="report_details">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
             <t t-call="true_report.report_details_documents" t-lang="o.company_id.partner_id.lang"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

Please help me to solve the issue. I will be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a beginner you should refer following link : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html

From this page you can understand qweb reports.

Comment: I think I need some more help than this. Can you please point out my mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
`<t t-call="web.external_layout">` instead of `<t t-call="web.html_container">`

Comment: I had same issue and I solved it with this. I don't know exactly how does it works but that worked for me.